# Cordova build ios gives an empty error message

Tags: ios, cordova, build

I am getting an empty error message when I try to run cordova build ios command.

[image: screenshot]

I tried removing and adding the platform again and also re-installing cordova with no luck.

version details are;
cordova@6.4.0
ios@4.3.1

following is the output when I run the command with --verbose on

[image: screenshot]

Thanks for help!

Comment: Got it working after I disconnect my device (iPad) from the Mac. I don't know the exact reason but sharing the experience since it may help someone in future.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered.

Comment: Same problem. Can't run on connected device. All certs are in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem here, which was indeed fixed after disconnecting the device from the Mac.